# What is the coefficient $\mu_\text{air}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am answering some exercises in thermodynamics, and I am still in trouble with some values and constants.
In the exercise, it is given: $\mu_\text{air}=1.8\cdot10^{-5}~\text{kg/m s}$. What for is this value used? In the case, I need to find some tensions in given points, and I know the speed profile of the air.

Other question: As I need the tension in some points, and it is about air, is it the same thing as pressure?

Answer (score 2):

$\mu$ is the dynamic [viscosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity). The [wall shear stress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_shear_stress#Shear_stress_in_fluids) is a force (per unit area) on the wall by the fluid, which has units of $Pa$. So, the velocity profile AND the viscosity together will give you a tension (see second link).